# Failover error interceptor for $http in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, promise, interceptor

Is it possible to implement a "responseError" interceptor for $http service that would trigger only if there is no specific failure handler defined elsewhere for the given http promise?

So that in case of an error in the response, the following expression `$http.get(...).success(...)` will execute some code in the interceptor, while the following one `$http.get(...).success(...).error(...)` won't.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a decorator:

```
app.config(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$exceptionHandler', function($delegate, $injector) {
        return function $broadcastingExceptionHandler(ex, cause) {
            $delegate(ex, cause);
            $injector.get('$rootScope').$broadcast('exception', ex, cause);
        }
    });
});
```

This example will catch all exceptions though, but you can examine the error and handle it appropriately.